# filtering stdout coming from a thread created with forkIO

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to run [doctest](https://github.com/sol/doctest/blob/master/src/Run.hs) via its API from a thread using forkIO:

```hs
    forkIO $ bracket 
            (cls>>putStrLn "Testing...")
            (\_->putStrLn "Waiting for file changes...")
            (\_->doctest ["src/MyProgram.hs"])
```

I'm using `bracket` (Control.Exception) because it's the only way I've found to reliably schedule the "Testing" and "Waiting" messages before and after respectively.  I'm doing all this inside an FSNotify loop watching for file changes.

My question is, I'd like to capture and transform the output (stdout and stderr) coming from doctest using simple sed-like filters.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Can't you send those messages to some channel (`Chan`) instead of stdout/err? I don't know if stdout can be easily filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't easily capture or redirect stdout and stderr for Haskell programs. Various hacks exist such as the [System.Posix.Redirect](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/system-posix-redirect-1.1.0.1/docs/System-Posix-Redirect.html) or [System.IO.Silently](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/silently-1.2.5.1/docs/System-IO-Silently.html) libraries, but they have a pile of caveats such as

- being POSIX-only, and
- messing with the file descriptors for your entire process, so they are not thread-safe and might interfere with other use of the handles.

In my experience the best thing to do is run your code in a [MonadLogger](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-logger-0.3.35/docs/Control-Monad-Logger.html) monad. This offers a lot of control over where the log messages go: when you invoke the monad you can use `runStdoutLoggingT`, `runChanLoggingT`, etc. or an arbitrary `IO` function of your own to handle the messages.

If you use a logging monad transformer, you'll want to import a lifted version of `bracket` to use with it. I really like using [Control.Exception.Safe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-exceptions-0.1.7.0/docs/Control-Exception-Safe.html) in any place you would normally use `Control.Exception` (for the liftedness and other safety reasons).